# How do I execute another function after async function is completed in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous

I'm instantiating following variable:

```
phoneViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(PhoneViewModel::class.java).also {it.initialRead()}
```

The initialRead() calls another function which retrieves data async. When I use the phoneViewModel variable in my application, the application crashes because initialRead() hasn't finished yet. How can I execute another function for example usePhoneViewModel() after the "async" instantiation has been finished?

```
public fun initialRead(onError: ((errorMessage: String) -> Unit)? = null) {
    if (!isDownloadError) {
        repository.initialRead(
            Action0 { isDownloadError = false},
            Action1 { error ->
                isDownloadError = true
                onError?.let {
                    val resources = getApplication<Application>().resources
                    onError.invoke(resources.getString(R.string.read_failed_detail))
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

and initialRead in the repo

```
fun initialRead(successHandler: Action0?, failureHandler: Action1<RuntimeException>) {
    relatedEntities.clear()

    if (initialReadDone && entities.size > 0) {
        observableEntities.setValue(entities)
        return
    }

    var dataQuery = DataQuery().from(entitySet)
    if (orderByProperty != null) {
        dataQuery = dataQuery.orderBy(orderByProperty, SortOrder.ASCENDING)
    }

    zGW_EXT_SHIP_APP_SRV_Entities.executeQueryAsync(dataQuery,
        Action1 { queryResult ->
            val entitiesRead = convert(queryResult.entityList)
            entities.clear()
            entities.addAll(entitiesRead)
            initialReadDone = true
            observableEntities.value = entitiesRead
            successHandler?.call()
        },
        failureHandler,
        httpHeaders)
}
```

Comment: Please be more precise about how exactly `initialRead` is async: does it return Java `Future`, `CompletableFuture` or some other similar type? Is it a Kotlin `suspend` function? Something else?

Comment: Use [`LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)

Answer (score 1):

Given this function I don't think you can. Add an `onSuccess` argument to your `initialRead`, e.g.:

```
public fun initialRead(onSuccess: (() -> Unit)? = null, onError: ((errorMessage: String) -> Unit)? = null) {
    if (!isDownloadError) {
        repository.initialRead(
            Action0 { 
                isDownloadError = false
                onSuccess?.invoke()
            },
            Action1 { error ->
                isDownloadError = true
                onError?.let {
                    val resources = getApplication<Application>().resources
                    onError.invoke(resources.getString(R.string.read_failed_detail))
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

and then pass what you want to do there:

```
ViewModelProvider(this).get(PhoneViewModel::class.java).also {
    it.initialRead(onSuccess = { usePhoneViewModel() })
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But usePhoneViewModel() is never called. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you are in `if (initialReadDone && entities.size > 0)` case? But this is just a guess and I suggest trying to debug it yourself.

Comment: Just debugged and it goes into executeQueryAsync and succesHandler?.call is called but my function usePhoneViewModel isn't called hmmm